# non-blocking setTimeout in javascript vs sleep in ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous

So, in javascript since it's event-driven by its nature it seems that setTimeout doesn't block. This means that if I do this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('sleeping');
}, 10);
console.log('prints first!!');
```

It will output `'prints first!!'` and then `'sleeping'`.

The js interpreter won't wait until setTimeout is done instead it executes the piece of code below it right away. When 10ms passes, then it executes the callback function.

Now I have been playing around with ruby recently. I know that it has non-blocking support in event-machine library. But I wonder if we can achieve something similar to setTimeout example I have just written in javascript with `sleep` or any function in ruby natively without event-machine support? Is this possible at all using closure proc or block or anything? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `setTimeout` function is nothing at all like `sleep` since the former is asynchronous and the latter is synchronous.

The Ruby `sleep` method, like its POSIX counterpart, halts execution of the script. The `setTimer` function in JavaScript triggers a callback at a future time.

If you want to trigger an asynchronous callback, you might need something like [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/) to run an event loop for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could get some very basic asynchronous behavior with threads:

```
timeout = Thread.new(Time.now + 3) do |end_time|
  while Time.now < end_time
    Thread.pass
  end
  puts "Ding!"
end

main = Thread.new do
  puts "Main"
end

main.join
timeout.join
```

I don't know if you want to go down the road of thread programming. That seems like overkill to me, but it's an option if you can't use EventMachine.

Comment: yeah it doesn't look like thread is going to be something I'll be using. i know async needs to be done with event machine, but i was just curious. thanks

Comment: The big problem with threads triggering async callbacks is trying to force the execution of that callback block on the calling thread. This is tricky unless you have a proper event loop where there's well defined places to execute them.